Expo Native View - How to add native dependencies
I'm trying to create a yandex map kit with Expo native view.
When I read the android document on Yandex, it asks me to add the following dependencies.
Open the project's build.gradle file. In the repositories section, add the Maven Central and Google Maven repositories:
repositories {
    ...
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
         url "http://maven.google.com/"
    }
}

Open the application's (module's) build.gradle file. In the dependencies section, add the following dependency:
dependencies
{
    // The lite library only contains the map, traffic layer,
    // LocationManager, and UserLocationLayer
    // and lets you download offline maps (in the paid version only).
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:maps.mobile:4.6.1-lite'

    // The full library supplements lite version features with car routing,
    // bike routing, pedestrian routing, and public transport routing,
    // search, suggest, geocoding, and panorama display.
    // implementation 'com.yandex.android:maps.mobile:4.6.1-full'
}

Which of the attached images should I add?

